# Composite of two fields contain a given quadratic extension, but each individual doesn't

Tags: fields, non-archimedean-fields

In fact, this question could be asked for arbitrary field extension. However, for simplicity I only ask the question for local field of characteristic 0. Let $E/F$ be a quadratic extension of padic field (we may assume $p\neq 2$ also for simplicity). Can we classify all the possible cases: $E_1/F$ and $E_2/F$ are finite extensions of $F$, both of which are disjoint from $E$, but the composite $E_1E_2:=E_1\otimes_{F} E_2$ contains $E$. THe most famous example is given by the biquadratic extensions $K/F$ such that $E_1,E_2,E$ are three intermediate quadratic extensions of $F$. Is there any example beyond this? Thanks very much for your comments.

Comment: Welcome, new contributor. This question seems more appropriate for math.stackexchange. Also, you might reconsider your claim that the "composite extension" is the tensor product.

Comment: @Laurent Moret-Bailly. Dear Professor Bailly, sorry I did not write clearly, I also assume $E_1$ and $E_2$ disjoint so that the tensor product is a field. Of course, if you like, you can put both of these two fields into $\overline{F}$ to talk about composite of fields. In fact, I first thought this problem was easy, but later I found I was wrong...

Comment: I disagree that this question is more appropriate for math.stackexchange. Without the $p$-adic assumption I would agree, as in the general case there is not much to do other than apply the Galois correspondence, but in the $p$-adic case it is possible that there exists a nice classification using the special structure of these field's Galois groups.